# setting different indicators for different groups in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I would like to know how to set different indicators for different groups in ExpandableListView.

I tried :

```
if(true condition for a group say groupA)
{
    getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
}
```

but the above code sets the indicator for all the groups in the view !
I want different indicators for all the groups like :

groupA having a different indicator;groupB having a different indicator;groupC having a different indicator

where groupA,groupB and groupC have certain number of children.

Can anyone suggest something ?

-Adithya.

Comment: Is there a solution for my requirement ? In case of yes please let me know.

Comment: A lot of time is past. I think (and hope) you solved your issue. If not, and for future users having the same problem, refer to this tutorial: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create different indicator in expandable listview.
First of all create Adapter for expandable listView.
Create custom layout for all different indicator.

Now in your getGroupView method

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            if (groupPosition == 0) {
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(INFLATE YOUT LAYOUT HERE, null);
            } else if (groupPosition == 1) {
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(INFLATE YOUT LAYOUT HERE, null);
            }else if (groupPosition == 2) {
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(INFLATE YOUT LAYOUT HERE, null);
            }
}
```

Try this this is work for me...
Hope this is helpful for you..

Comment: I vaguely remember that i had worked on something like this long time back. I will have to write the entire code and see :)

Comment: Let me know if it's working or not because In my current app I have many expandable list and I resolve that issue using this code and working fine. If this answer is helpful for you than accept it.